# NSDictionary Not Storing Information

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For some weird reason golferStats is not storing info correctly...

I cut out a bunch of stuff in this code to the bare basics why is is still not working?

**Problem:** The last NSLOG returns nil when it should return a huge array...

```
NSMutableDictionary *golferStats = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
golferStats = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"golferStats"];

[golferStats setObject:golferTwoIconCounter forKey:golferName]; //golferName is k

[userDefaults setObject:golferStats forKey:@"golferStats"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
NSLog(@"SAVED SCORE CARD");
NSLog(@"%@",[golferStats objectForKey:@"k"]);
```

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary *golferStats = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; golferStats = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"golferStats"];` <-- this is BADLY leaking memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSMutableDictionary *golferStats = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`

<strike>`golferStats = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"golferStats"];`</strike>

...

`[golferStats release];`

You first create an `NSDictionary` and then you assign over top of it, thus leaking memory and presumably getting `nil` back from user defaults.  `setObject:forKey:` in the `nil` dictionary is a no-op, and then you are setting it back into the user defaults.

**EDIT:**

Try checking if there is a dictionary first:

```
NSDictionary *golferStats = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"golferStats"];
if (golferStats == nil) {
    golferStates = [NSDictionary dictionary]; // this will not leak
}
...
```

Comment: This is correct if OP doesn't want to preserve any other existing dictionary entries, if they do happen to exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the existing contents of the dictionary in cases where it already *does* exist, do this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *golferStats = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"golferStats"];
if (!golferStats) golferStats = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

[golferStats setObject:golferTwoIconCounter forKey:golferName];
[userDefaults setObject:golferStats forKey:@"golferStats"];
[userDefaults synchronize];

// no [golferStats release] because of autorelease above
```